# Swift alamofire response JSON convert to one lined JSON

Tags: swift, xcode, alamofire

I'm developing ios apps for the first time, and I use Alamofire and Swiftyjson to handle networking, but I don't know what is wrong with Alamofire, every time I parse JSON its output with space and like that 
example :

```
{
   "ref_number":"EPFNKS",
   "datetime_of_booking":"2018-05-08 13:13",
   "datetime_pay_by":"2018-05-08 23:13",
   "nta":1250100,
   "fare_details":[
      {
         "basic":1070000,
         "tax":107000,
         "iwjr":5000,
         "insurance":0,
         "fuel":0,
         "adm":100000,
         "total":1282000,
         "generation":"adult",
         "surcharge":"0",
         "discount":"0"
      }
   ],
   "flights":{
      "go":[
         {
            "flight_num":"JT 912",
            "depart_port":"BPN",
            "depart_city":"Balikpapan",
            "depart_time":"18:05",
            "depart_date":"2018-05-10",
            "depart_datetime":"2018-05-10 18:05",
            "arrive_port":"BDO",
            "arrive_city":"Bandung",
            "arrive_time":"19:05",
            "arrive_date":"2018-05-10",
            "arrive_datetime":"2018-05-10 19:05",
            "class":"eco",
            "seat_class":"b"
         }
      ],
      "back":null
   },
   "inv_number":null
}
```

because i wanna send that json again to server, i have to convert it to onelined utf8 encoded json like this :

```
{"ref_number":"EPFNKS","datetime_of_booking":"2018-05-08 13:13","datetime_pay_by":"2018-05-08 23:13","nta":1250100,"fare_details":[{"basic":1070000,"tax":107000,"iwjr":5000,"insurance":0,"fuel":0,"adm":100000,"total":1282000,"generation":"adult","surcharge":"0","discount":"0"}],"flights":{"go":[{"flight_num":"JT 912","depart_port":"BPN","depart_city":"Balikpapan","depart_time":"18:05","depart_date":"2018-05-10","depart_datetime":"2018-05-10 18:05","arrive_port":"BDO","arrive_city":"Bandung","arrive_time":"19:05","arrive_date":"2018-05-10","arrive_datetime":"2018-05-10 19:05","class":"eco","seat_class":"b"}],"back":null},"inv_number":null}
```

how can I convert JSON that have whitespaces to online?

thanks

Comment: You should get and send JSON as *data* anyway. Don't mess with the JSON *strings* except for debugging. // There's already tons of questions and answers about JSON in Swift. Please do some research. Hint: "prettyPrinted".

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire has some really interesting ways to handle code. Honestly, I'd say, drop the SwiftyJSON dependency because you are doing it the hard way. Just work with the data directly by using Alamofire's .responseData  chain method.

I want to mention that, as of Swift 4, "Codable" classes make everything so much better for decoding and encoding objects to do exactly what you are trying to do here in a more object oriented way. You just have to deal with "try-do-catch" statements as well as a possible encoder and decoder in extreme cases. This will make your code more robust.

[You can find a great tutorial on how to go about that here](https://medium.com/swiftly-swift/swift-4-decodable-beyond-the-basics-990cc48b7375)